# document.referrer not returning full url

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the organic search keyword for my site using document.referrer. I am having trouble in using document.referrer. It is not returning the full URL.

For example: When I search on Google like **"HTML DOM referrer Property"** and click the first result (w3schools link).

In w3schools, I can see only the

"https://www.google.co.in/"

but not

"https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=HTML+DOM+referrer+Property" or

"https://www.google.co.in/urlsa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiGxv3SyOTIAhUIHo4KHRCyB54&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fprop_doc_referrer.asp&usg=AFQjCNFNiXvO_JozIUUi3Q7I2lHcJ18NhA&sig2=LEgMJ7G1206-FIMQFDmaig".

How can I get the full url to find the organic search and keyword? Or Please help me to achieve this in some other way.

Comment: [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: @Andreas `window.location.search` returns empty when I Google my site and visit the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google (and also Yahoo) does not pass the parameters to the referrer string, but for example Bing does. If you need to optimize your keywords for Google, you need to use their [[image]google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics) tools.